# How to marshal FilePart of type application/json to a POJO in spring webflux functional endpoint handler?

Tags: functional-programming, marshalling, multipartform-data, spring-webflux, multipart

I receive a multipart request with some parts representing Json files that I need to convert to POJOs, in annotation based controller I could use

```
@RequestPart("person") Person
```

to marshal that part to a Person POJO.
with functional endpoints, I can get the parts through

```
request.body(BodyExtractors.toParts())
```

but I can't figure out how to marshal the relevant part to a pojo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jackson2JsonDecoder in webflux for that. Simple example assuming multipart form-data.

```
return serverRequest
        .multipartData()
        .map(MultiValueMap::toSingleValueMap)
        .map(stringPartMultiValueMap -> stringPartMultiValueMap.get("person"))
        .flatMap(part -> new Jackson2JsonDecoder()
            .decodeToMono(part.content(),
                ResolvableType.forClass(Person.class), null, null)
            .map(o -> (Person) o))
        .flatMap(person -> ServerResponse.ok().body(Mono.just(person), Person.class));
```

Comment: Thanks, Nipuna, that did it.

Functional endpoints seems too cumbersome though, I think I'll go with annotation based.